# Mule Expression to get individual object from a Json Array

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component, mule-el

Want to extract each object from my json payload which looks like this: Need to pass each object from this map into splitter or collection splitter. I cannot use foreach scope here.

```
[
    {
        "Name": null,
        "Key": "4",
        "Header": {
        "Id": "14"
        }
    },
    {
        "Name": null,
        "Key": "5",
        "Header": {
        "Id": "15"
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the entire object from the array we can use simple #[payload] and this will take care just like for each scope.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to parse and access the JSON elements then 
`**<json:json-to-object-transformer/>**` is the way to do the trick. 
**`java.util.HashMap or java.util.List or java.util.Map`** 
depends on the type of your JSON data. 
You can also use **`java.lang.Object`**

Comment: You can also use #[json:data/field]

Comment: I would recommending not using the `#[json:data/field]` expression. The JsonPath expression evaluator was deprecated. More info. on this can be found here: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/json-module-reference.

Comment: I am still getting exception. even if i use java.util.List or java.lang.Object. org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerMessagingException: The object transformed is of type: "SimpleDataType{type=java.lang.String, mimeType='*/*', encoding='null'}", but the expected return type is "SimpleDataType{type=java.util.List, mimeType='application/json', encoding='null'}". (org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerMessagingException)

Comment: After collection splitter, had to add object to json transformer to get rid of the above exception <json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="java.util.List" doc:name="JSON to Object"/>
 <collection-splitter doc:name="Collection Splitter"/>
 <json:object-to-json-transformer doc:name="Object to JSON"/>

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this :
1) As mentioned by Vijay, use json-to-object transformer to map input json to any Collection type e.g.

```
 <json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="java.util.List" doc:name="JSON to Object"/>
  <collection-splitter doc:name="Collection Splitter"/>
```

2) Use dataweave to get a Collection from input json data :

```
<dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message">
            <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/java
---
payload 
]]></dw:set-payload>
        </dw:transform-message>
<collection-splitter doc:name="Collection Splitter"/>
```

Comment: Getting the below Exception when used dataweave script as suggested Root Exception stack trace:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object "com.mulesoft.weave.reader.ByteArraySeekableStream" not of correct type. It must be of type "{interface java.lang.Iterable,interface java.util.Iterator,interface org.mule.routing.MessageSequence,interface java.util.Collection}"
 at org.mule.util.collection.EventToMessageSequenceSplittingStrategy.split(EventToMessageSequenceSplittingStrategy.java:65)

Comment: What is your input type to dataweave ? is it json or something else?